# Does anyone know how to implement a secure CNG key store in C#?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

Or is there a standard, default one provided in 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [**CngKey**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.aspx) Class and [**System.Security.Cryptography Namespace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx)
Along with, you this might be helpful as well:

- [**CLR Security at CodePlex**](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I have been and am trying to work out how to use the Windows key store as I know it was available via a more indirect route but I've not found anything more than: http://www.jensign.com/KeyPal/index.html

Comment: Or, could you have, perhaps, been referring to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cngprovider_properties.aspx ?